# Put the information from a leaf in a list

Tags: list, tree, prolog, dcg

I want to write a program that puts the information from the leaves in a tree in a list. I tried doing this:

```
leaves(l(_), [_]). 
leaves(b(B1, B2), [L]):- leaves(B1, [L1]), leaves(B2, [L2]). append(L1, L2, L).
```

But it gives me `L=[_A]`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your code, the correct code looks like this:

```
leaves(l(X), [X]).
leaves(b(B1, B2), L):- leaves(B1, L1), leaves(B2, L2), append(L1, L2, L).
```

I think the main problem was the use of `_`. It's an anonymous variable, it means “anything can be here”. And if you have it twice in one term, both `_` are different variables.

Also, you have `.` before `append` instead of `,`. My Prolog interpreter (SWI-Prolog) reported two warnings about singleton variables, you shouldn't ignore those.

Answer (score 2):

Also, as you describe a list, consider using DCG notation:

```
leaves(l(L))     --> [L].
leaves(b(B1,B2)) --> leaves(B1), leaves(B2).
```

Usage: `?- phrase(leaves(Tree), Leaves)`.

Answer (score 0):

debug your program with `trace`, that would execute your query step by step so you can see why the result is wrong. basically that variable given as list entries usually caused by singleton variables (declared but not used, i.e. instantiated) as svick has stated.